# how to ignore timestamp while converting String to Date Object in angular

Tags: angular

I need to convert String to Date object in angular5 without considering the timezone

Now I am using

```
dateValue = new Date(dateValue );
```

Here the dateValue is String coming from services as **2016-01-05**
when I am converting it to Date object the dateValue is becoming **Tue Jan 05 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

I need to have the same dateValue after converting to Date object also by ignoring timezone

Comment: you can use pipe function to show only date in ur HTML like `{{dateString |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}`

Comment: Did you tried `new Date(this.dateValue).toDateString()`?

Comment: It IS the same date value. You can't just "ignore" parts of the `Date` object. You could set hours to midnight like so: `dateValue.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: If you use moment: 
removeTimezone(date: Date): Date {
  const mDate = moment(date);
  return new Date(mDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

Comment: I cant use Pipe in Html as I am using <p-calender> component - @CodeChanger

Comment: How can I use moment can you eloborate more - @J.Pinxten

Comment: I have attached the documentation link, if you are interested in using moment, you can have a look at that link. :)

Comment: It is saying setHours(0,0,0,0) is not a function - @ritaj

Comment: That's impossible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Comment: It worked if I say dateValue.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); It did not work when I tried with dateValue = new Date(dateValue.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) );   Thanks  -@ritaj

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to render the date on your view, you can simply use {{dateString | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}, as mentioned by codechanger.

But, if you would like to format your date within your component.ts, you can import DatePipe, or FormatDate within the component.

1) DatePipe:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {   

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add DatePipe to your providers in your module.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

2) formatDate:

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.locale);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatePipe,

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'    
.
.

export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  dateValue: string = "2016-01-05";

  constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe) {  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dateValue = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(this.dateValue),"yyyy-MM-dd");
  }
}
```

If you use DatePipe, you need to declare DatePipe as provider in App Module.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
.
.
providers:[DatePipe]
```

Here is [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdutum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is converting the Date object to required format as I am using <p-calender> component it is not accepting the converted value in [(ngModel)] now

Comment: Getting  'Unexpected literal at position 2' since I am using <p-calender> component

Comment: Can you post your code, What are you doing? Also with the p-calendar control.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can also try this

```
    dateInfo= '2019-01-30';

    dateData = new Date(this.dateInfo);

    this.dateData.toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

below is the stackblitz for that  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thnran

Comment: Getting 'Unexpected literal at position 2' error since I am using <p-calender> component

Comment: @Shiny can u check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966296/unexpected-literal-at-position-2

Answer (score 0):

Here you nee to write below methods to format date

Using below method you can get the formatted date string.

```
formatDate(date: Date): string {
    return (""+ date.getFullYear()  + "-" + date.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + date.getDate() )
}
```

Here you will convert string to Date ignoring local timestamp.

```
getDate(date): Date {
  var dateParts = date.split("-");
  return new Date(Date.parse(this.stringDate)); 
}
```

**Here is [demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dx5xpa?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using datepipe as already suggested. You can also try moment to get the specified result.

```
dateValue = new Date(dateValue );
dateValue = moment(dateValue).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you are new to moment, have a look at [this](https://momentjs.com/). It is very easy to use.

If you are using npm then just run this command:

```
npm install moment --save
```

After the simply import it at top of your component file as below:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Now you are ready to use it.

Comment: Getting 'Unexpected literal at position 2' since I am using <p-calender> component -@Tasnim Fabiha

Comment: to get rid of this error you need to assign date object to your ngModel. Can you edit the question with briefly explaining your code and what purpose you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below approach -

```
var currentDate = new Date('2016-01-05');

var date = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth();
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();

var dateString =(month + 1) + "-" +  date + "-" + year;
```